# функция или скрипт, для изменении значения в ячейках при изменении значения в другой ячейке

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Таблица google sheets, создана для планирования.
Верхняя строка настроена на автоматический вывод номеров недели из расчета на три месяца и пересчитывается автоматически(то есть: в А1 всегда будет сегодняшняя неделя).
Ниже в столбцах заносятся данные.
Проблема в том что при обновлении номера недели данные в столбцах остаются на своих местах.
Подскажите как можно перезаписывать данные в столбцах, чтобы они соответствовали своей неделе?

Comment: Неправильный подход. Нужно или накапливать данные справа, не сдвигая линейку дат, или предыдущие данные дозаписывать в отдельную таблицу (базу), оставляя пустую таблицу для новой недели.

Comment: Вариант: добавить новые столбцы и дописать новые даты

Comment: Спасибо за варианты, сейчас я применил статическую верхнюю строку с датами на год и автоматическим перерасчетом номеров недели в зависимости от года - это решает проблему, но вопрос был задан для того что бы узнать существует ли возможность с помощью функций или скриптов смещать данные в определенном диапазоне ячеек в зависимости от изменения значения в другом диапазоне (или другой ячейке)

Comment: Написать процедуру на JS, который будет копировать данные и сдвигать их на несколько столбцов левее. Но смещение одних данных относительно других - не очень хорошая задумка. Волне возможно, что при каком-либо сбое данные так и зависнут сдвинутыми относительно дат. И если уж двигать, то лучше по варианту из комментария №2, (тоже с помощью JS)